# problem in comparing element of two array and if element matches then modifies another array value with some condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to compare  x and  z and if element in x is present in  z then push element of y in  temp else push 0 in temp at the end length of z and temp should be equal.
below is my code ---

```
  var x=[00,03,06,21]
        var y=[79,11,18,14]
        var temp=[]
        var z=[00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]

 for(var i=0;i<z.length;i++){
                for(j=0;j<x.length;j++){
                    if(z[i]==x[j]){
                      //  alert("hello")
                        temp.push(y[j])
                    }                  
                }
                if(z[i]!=x[j]){
                    temp.push(0)
                }
            }
            console.log(temp)
            console.log(z)

    i getting the output as -

    //temp  (29) [79, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
   //z     (25) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24] 

        expected output --

        //temp (25) [79, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  14, 0, 0, 0]
        //z    (25) [0,  1, 2, 3, 4,  5, 6,  7, 8,  9, 10,  11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 
                     24]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you found a common value, you need to continue the outer loop. If not found, push after finishing the inner loop.

BTW, do not forget to declare all variables.

```js
var x = [0, 3, 6, 21],
    y = [79, 11, 18, 14],
    temp = [],
    z = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24];

outer: for (let i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
        if (z[i] === x[j]) {
            temp.push(y[j]);
            continue outer;
        }
    }
    temp.push(0);
}
console.log(temp);
console.log(z);
```

A version without a label.

```js
var x = [0, 3, 6, 21],
    y = [79, 11, 18, 14],
    temp = [],
    z = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24];

for (let i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    let value = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
        if (z[i] === x[j]) {
            value = y[j];
            break;
        }
    }
    temp.push(value);
}
console.log(temp);
console.log(z);
```

Finally, a shorter approach with an object for the replacement values.

```js
var x = [0, 3, 6, 21],
    y = [79, 11, 18, 14],
    z = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
    values = x.reduce((r, k, i) => (r[k] = y[i], r), {}),
    temp = z.map(k => values[k] || 0);

console.log(temp);
console.log(z);
```